# How to unpack variables from tuple and give them names from another tuple?

Tags: python

I have two tuples - one with the keys and another one with a collection of variables of different types (list, float64, int and array) generate with the help of the following formula from a dictionary:

```
keys, values = zip(*[(key, value) for (key, value) in data_dict.items()])
```

Now I would like to retrieve the variables from the list of values and give them names from the list of keys. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean *"give them names"*? Why don't you just *use the dictionary?*

Comment: I need those variables once again because I run the code once a day and I use spyder data file (it saves all the variables I use to a dictionary) to keep my variables updated.

Comment: Could you give some more context? If it saves them all to a dictionary, *why not use the dictionary?*

Comment: there is a code that I run on a daily basis. in order not to recalculate the values, that were already calculated, I store them in a spyder datafile, which, in turn, saves all the variables I use to a dictionary. I need to unpack this dictionary into the variables again so that I can run the code again next day without any adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create variables in the global scope from your dictionary, perhaps you could update it like this:

```
globals().update(data_dict)
```

without unpacking the dict.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If it's really not possible to store your key/value pairs in a `dict` and serialise them to data file in that format, you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to dynamically construct assignment statements

```
>>> key = 'foo_var'
>>> val = 'foo_val'
>>> exec('{key} = \'{val}\''.format(key=key, val=val))
>>> foo_var
'foo_val'
```

I'd explore the `dict` approach first though, in case that can work for you. There are lots of good reasons to avoid runtime code generation using `exec` and `eval` where possible.